# Jquery on('click') not working after initializing menuzord

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following on click method on an Element:

```js
$('.searchInputContainer a.dnnSearchBoxClearText').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $wrap = $this.parent();
    $('.searchInputContainer input').val('').focus();
    $this.removeClass('dnnShow');
    $('.searchSkinObjectPreview', $wrap).remove();
    return false;
});
```

But after initializing the menuzord element, the on click method isn't working anymore.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#menuzord").menuzord({
            align: "left",
            indicatorFirstLevel: "<span class='hide-on-desktop hide-on-tablet'>&nbsp;<i class='fa bw-ico-arrow-small-down' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>",
            indicatorSecondLevel: "<i class='bw-ico-arrow-small-down hide-on-mobile' aria-hidden='true'></i><i class='bw-ico-arrow-small-down hide-on-desktop hide-on-tablet' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
        });
    });
```

Does anyone know what this can be due to? Or maybe Menuzord overwrites the event?

Comment: What do you see in the console(f12)?

Comment: Just some information that JQMIGRATE is installed. So no errors.

Answer (score 0):

After using the selector in the JQuery "on" method, it worked:

```js
$('.searchInputContainer').on('click', 'a.dnnSearchBoxClearText', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $wrap = $this.parent();
    $('.searchInputContainer input').val('').focus();
    $this.removeClass('dnnShow');
    $('.searchSkinObjectPreview', $wrap).remove();
    return false;
});
```

But I don't understand the different. Would be nice if someone can explain it to me.